# How to use Chinese IP only on Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Question as captioned.

I know how to set the exit node to USA by setting the exit node parameter to "us" and to England by "gb". But when I set that parameter to "cn", it seems fail to use a Chinese IP. Sometimes I even can't open Tor Browser properly.

Maybe I have done something wrong. Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: Currently I can't find find running exit nodes in China. So without any you'll have a hard time connecting to it. :-)

Comment: Tor is blocked in china, so no wonder guard and exit nodes are getting blocked there. Is there a real reason why do you want to use a chinese exit node in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely you will ever find an exit node in China. In theory, the ExitNodes feature can help with that, so putting 'cn' there was the right idea - but without any exit nodes actually running in China, that won't work correctly. It seems like Tor cannot help you achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting 'hk' for Hong Kong. Checking with whatismyip.com sometimes my location is reported as China and when signing up for a new Gmail account it sometimes auto-selects China as my country in the sign up form.

Depending on your needs this may be close enough for you.